# Define different style for \section & \subsection command

Tags: macros, sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I am trying to customize my `\section` and `\subsection` command in such a way that they have two different styles.  With the following code I am able to draw squared shades around the section numbering.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{extarticle}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{helvet}
      \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
      \titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\mdseries}
      \titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}
    \usepackage{color}
    \makeatletter
      \definecolor{sectcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
      \let\origsection\section 
      \let\origsubsection\subsection
      \def\thesectiontext{\@arabic\c@section.}
      \def\thesubsectiontext{\thesectiontext\@arabic\c@subsection}
      \global\newsavebox{\sectbox}
      \def\makesectbox#1{\savebox\sectbox{\colorbox{sectcolor}
          {\makebox[1.47cm][r]{\normalfont\large\bfseries#1}}}}
      \renewcommand \thesection {\usebox{\sectbox}}
      \renewcommand \thesubsection {\usebox{\sectbox}}
      \renewcommand\section{\@ifstar{\myheading}{\mysection}}
      \newcommand\mysection[1]{\sectprelude{section}%
          {\thesectiontext}\origsection{#1}\mdseries}
      \titleformat{\mysection}
          {\fontsize{16}{19}\selectfont}{\thesection}{1em}{}
      \newcommand\myheading[1]{\sectprelude{section}%
          {\thesectiontext}\origsection*{#1}}
      \renewcommand\subsection[1]{\sectprelude{subsection}%
          {\thesubsectiontext}\origsubsection{#1}}
      \newcommand\sectprelude[2]{%
          \addtocounter{#1}{1}\makesectbox{#2}\addtocounter{#1}{-1}}
    \makeatother 
    \makeatletter
      \def\@seccntformat#1{\llap{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}} 
    \makeatother 


    \begin{document}

    \section{Neuromancer}
    \vspace{1em}
     Count Zero Interrupt ...
    \section{Foundation series}

    \subsection{Foundation}
    \subsection{Foundation and Empire}
    \end{document}
```

The result of this code can be seen here:[image]

I however want, that there are no shaded boxes around the `\subsection` numbering and that the section number of the `\section` command is aligned with the section number of the `\subsection` command (meaning all the 2's on the left side of the dot have the same horizontal coordinate)

Does someone know a solution?

Comment: Have you exhausted the possibilities of `sectsty & `titlesec` packages or the special commands in `memoir` class?

Comment: This depends on the class in addition. For the standard classes there is `\@sect` doing the basic stuff, it's possible to decide there if it's a section or a `subsection`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\definecolor{sectcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\selectfont\bfseries}
  {\llap{\colorbox{sectcolor}{%
    \makebox[1.4cm][r]{%
      \makebox[0.7cm][l]{\thesection.\hfill}}%
      }\hspace{10pt}%
    }%
  }
  {0em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\llap{\colorbox{white}{%
    \makebox[1.4cm][r]{%
      \makebox[0.7cm][l]{\thesubsection\hfill}}%
      }\hspace{10pt}%
    }%
  }
  {0em}
  {}

\begin{document}

\section{Neuromancer}
Count Zero Interrupt ...
\section{Foundation series}
\subsection{Foundation}
\subsection{Foundation and Empire}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using instead

```
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\selectfont\bfseries}
  {\llap{\colorbox{sectcolor}{%
    \makebox[1.4cm][l]{%
      \thesection.}%
      }\hspace{10pt}%
    }%
  }
  {0em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\llap{\colorbox{white}{%
    \makebox[1.4cm][l]{%
      \thesubsection}%
      }\hspace{10pt}%
    }%
  }
  {0em}
  {}
```

you get the numbers flushed left inside the color boxes:

[image]